# PHP stuck in safe_mode

Tags: php, configuration, safe-mode

Even though I've set

safe_mode = Off

in php.ini, restarted apache, and even rebooted the system...

when I try to execute set_time_limit(0) in my application, it throws the warning that set_time_limit cannot be st in safe mode.

This has been erratic behavior;  earlier when I set safe_mode to Off, the system worked fine.  But later on, seemingly autonomously, safe_mode has returned, and my application breaks due to the time_limit.

Is there anything I can check?  I fear that my system has been compromised.

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` show safe mode being disabled?  Maybe you changed the wrong configuration file, or the change was not saved because of a permission problem, etc.etc.  Also, what OS and version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I am using fedora redhat 7, PHP 5.2.6

phpinfo says that there is a "Local Setting" which is "On", vs. a Master Setting, which is "Off".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP settings can appear in a number of different locations - it's likely that the setting in php.ini is being overridden by a setting elsewhere.

You might want to check:

- Your Apache configuration, such as httpd.conf/apache.conf or virtual host configuration.
- An .htaccess file

Given that phpinfo is talking about a "Local setting" that sounds a little bit like a .htaccess setting to me but it could be in another part of Apache's config.

It's not usual for PHP to be placed in safe mode on a 'default install', indeed it will be deprecated in future PHP versions if it isn't already.  It's strange then that you have safe mode enabled without knowing it - perhaps some other app enabled it as part of its install script or maybe you copy-pasted some example configuration from somewhere?  I dunno.

Comment: I believe Plesk is over-riding my php.ini settings, but i do not know how to over-ride this.

Comment: Try this then: http://www.nickhammond.com/2008/04/20/turning-off-php-safe-mode-with-plesk/

Comment: Thank you Thomas, this was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running XAMPP, then the correct php.ini file is located at `xampp\apache\bin\php.ini`. Modifying `xampp\php\php.ini` won't affect anything.

(Paths may differ between OSes, this is for Windows).